# Query to find row count of tables based on column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I  have been trying to find out total count of rows in each tables which are de-activated.
In my DB I have 20 tables with column IsActive.

I have tried below cursor,however it is getting error saying Invalid object name @Namee.

```
Create table #t
(
NoOfRows bigint,
)

Declare @Namee Varchar(500)
Declare @GetName Cursor
Set     @Getname = Cursor for 
Select table_name from information_Schema.columns
where column_name='isactive'Open @Getname
Fetch Next From @Getname into @Namee
While @@Fetch_Status=0
Begin 
insert into #t Select count(*) from @Namee where isactive=0
Fetch Next From @Getname into @Namee
End
Close @GetName
Deallocate @GetName
select * from #t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
insert into #t Select count(*) from @Namee where isactive=0
```

with

```
 exec ('insert into #t Select count(*) from ' + @Namee + ' where isactive=0')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
exec sp_msforeachtable '
if exists(
select * from sys.tables as t
join sys.columns as c on t.object_id = c.object_id
where t.name = ''?'' and c.name = ''IsActive'')

select count(*) 
from [?] 
where isactive=0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example query, this should work. It will also be much faster than using the cursor

```
select
    OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) as table_name
,   p.row_count
from sys.columns c
 join sys.dm_db_partition_stats p
    on c.object_id = p.object_id
    and p.index_id < 2
where c.name = 'IsActive'
```

Comment: That would only return rowcount for each such table. But he needs a filtered result.

Comment: You're right. I misread the question. Your answer is what I would go with.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't tested them, I would go with either Mike's or Denis's answer.

However, the problem here is the line:

```
insert into #t Select count(*) from @Namee where isactive=0
```

you are using @Namee like it is a table, but it is really a string with a table name.  You would have to build the SQL dynamically and then exec it:

```
exec 'insert into #t select count(*) from ' + @Namee + ' where isactive=0'
```